# How to pass object in Dart by value only?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to get a copy of an object property then modify the copy but it turns out the source object was also modified. How can I prevent it?

```
void main() async{
  var b = new B();
  var l = await b.letters();
  print(b._letters.toString());
  l.removeWhere((l) => l == 'b');
  print(l.toString());
  print(b._letters.toString());
}


class B{
  List<String> _letters = ['a','b','c'];
  Future<List<String>> letters()  async{
    return _letters;
  }
}
```

The above result is

```
[a, b, c]
[a, c]
[a, c]
```

But I want

```
[a, b, c]
[a, c]
[a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a copy with `List.from`:

```dart
class B {
  List<String> _letters = ['a','b','c'];
  Future<List<String>> letters() async {
    // Copy the _letters list
    return _letters.toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using `List.of(list)`, `list.toList()` or `[...list]` over `List.from(list)`. All of those have better static type checking. Only use `List.from` when you need to create a list of a *different* type than the original, and one which is not just a supertype of the original list's type.

Comment: @lrn That's perfect!

Comment: @HeeroYuy If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.